# NGinX Rate Limiting With No Burst

Tags: nginx

I am experiencing unusual behavior with rate limiting in NGinX. I have been tasked with supporting 10 requests per second and not to use the burst option. I am using the nodelay option to reject any requests over my set rate.

My config is:

`..
http
{
    ..
    limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=one:10m rate=10r/s;
    ..
    server
    {
        ..
        location /
        {
            limit_req zone=one nodelay;
            limit_req_status 503;
            ..
        }
    }
}`

The behavior I am seeing is if a request is sent before a response is received from a previous request NGinX will return a 503 error. I see this behavior with as little as 2 requests in a second.

Is there something missing from my configuration which is causing this behavior?
Is the burst option needed to service multiple requests at once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Burst Works like a queue. No delay means the requests will not be delayed for next second. If you are not specifying a queue then you are not allowing any other simultaneous  request to come in from that IP. The zone takes effect for per ip as your key is $binary_remote_addr.

You need a burst.